# how to use lottie-react in astro build framework

Tags: reactjs, lottie, astrojs, static-site-generation

I was trying astro build and want to use lottie json files for animations, but there is no documented resource that describe how can we use lottie-react in astro build framework.

I try lottie-react npm package everything works fine in dev, but when i try to build it throw and error as we can not generate static content from lottie-react library.

Is this even possible to use lottie-react in astro, if yes ? then please explain in detail!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First some references

- lottie-web adapation to react : https://www.npmjs.com/package/lottie-react
- adding react to Astro : https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/integrations-guide/react/

Steps I used to recreate the example other steps possible too

```
npm create astro@latest -- --template minimal
```

- enter directory name
- don't install dependencies
- typescript relaxed

```
pnpm install
npx astro add react
```

### This does not work

a simple and direct integration on the same page does not work
`index.astro`

```html
---
import Lottie from "lottie-react";
import groovyWalkAnimation from "../lottie/groovyWalk.json";
---
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Astro</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Astro</h1>
        <Lottie animationData={groovyWalkAnimation} loop={true} client:load/>
    </body>
</html>
```

### This is how it works

it works when placing lottie-react on a .jsx file
`Lottie.jsx`
which is taken from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/lottie-react section (Using the Hook)

```
import React from "react";
import { useLottie } from "lottie-react";
import groovyWalkAnimation from "../lottie/groovyWalk.json";

const App = () => {
  const options = {
    animationData: groovyWalkAnimation,
    loop: true
  };

  const { View } = useLottie(options);

  return <>{View}</>;
};

export default App;
```

`index.astro`

```html
---
import Lottie from './Lottie';
---
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.svg" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <meta name="generator" content={Astro.generator} />
        <title>Astro</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Astro</h1>
        <Lottie client:load/>
    </body>
</html>
```

## Working example

- Github repo : https://github.com/MicroWebStacks/astro-examples_react-lottie
- StackBlitz : https://stackblitz.com/github/MicroWebStacks/astro-examples_react-lottie
- Gitpod : https://gitpod.io/?on=gitpod#https://github.com/MicroWebStacks/astro-examples_react-lottie